# Why import hook doesn't work when hook to ‘win32api’ for python?

Tags: python, import, hook

This is the demo show import hook for Python. (http://docs.python.org/2/library/imputil.html)
However, I followed it like this:

```
import sys, __builtin__

original_import = None

# Replacement for __import__()
def import_hook(name, globals=None, locals=None, fromlist=None):
    return original_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist)

# Save the original hooks
original_import = __builtin__.__import__
original_reload = __builtin__.reload

# Now install our hooks
__builtin__.__import__ = import_hook

import os
import sys

import win32api
```

So, when `import win32api`, the `import_hook` will be called, however, I am not sure why it doesn't work for `win32api`, the erros message shows:

```
TypeError: import_hook() takes at most 4 arguments (5 given)
```

But if I calls `import sys` or `import os`, it works fine. 
My Python is 2.7.2 , OS is Windows 7.

Comment: [you forgot 5th argument (`level`)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

Comment: Thanks very much! I didn't find out that is still another args. Could you post answer so that I can accept it ?

Comment: never mind, I already accept it ! you are genius!